# How to send and receive friend request to XMPP server using smack Api

Tags: android

How to send and receive friend request in android using SMACK API.I know to add user to roster i can use **roster.createEntry("abcd@203.xxx.xx.xx", "abcd", null);** but i want to ask to user if he/she wants to add me to their roster or not.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Roster, just send him/her a presence, with the subscribe type, then when he/she receives the subscribe presence, you show the Accept/Decline dialog. If he/she accepts, then he/she sends back a subscribed type presence and also a subscribe type presence and creates a roster(it is needed to set the rosters name). Now the user who initially sent the subscribe, receives a subscribed and a subscribe type presence from the user he/she added as a friend. Receiving these, he/she sends back automatically a subscribed type presence and creates a roster.

Simpler way:

```
User1 ----subscribe---> User2

show dialog
if accept
User2 ----subscribed---> User1
User2 ----subscribe---> User1
create roster with name(which is actually modifying the roster, since the subscribe creates one, without a name)

without dialog
User1 ----subscribed---> User2
create roster with name(which is actually modifying the roster, since the subscribe creates one, without a name)
end if

else
User2 ----unsubscribed---> User1
User1 delete roster
end else
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: me devloping apps in android so i can send frends requrest to one user but frend cannot check reive request

Comment: You need to have a listener. I think in your case, you need to use a roster listener, but I'm not sure. It has to be a listener, that listens to presence changes, because the request comes in a presence stanza.

Comment: @CoronaPintu -did you get something?